I want to sort data df.groupby.agg.sort_values. Having issues
df.groupby('Agent Shift').agg(
    {'CSAT Score': ['count','sum','mean']}
).sort_values(ascending=False)

Output
TypeError: DataFrame.sort_values() missing 1 required positional argument: 'by'
Then I add Agent Shift in sort_values
df.groupby('Agent Shift').agg({'CSAT Score': ['count','sum','mean']}).sort_values(by=[Agent Shift],ascending=False)

Output
CSAT Score
count   sum mean
Agent Shift         
Split   3648    16151   4.427357
Night   1316    5644    4.288754
Morning 41426   173554  4.189495
Evening 33677   144015  4.276361
Afternoon   5840    25067   4.292295

When I am trying to sort by count, sum or mean I get error
df.groupby('Agent Shift').agg({'CSAT Score': ['count','sum','mean']}).sort_values(by=[count],ascending=False)

Output
'count'

When I am trying to sort by the CSAT Score it gives this error as well
df.groupby('Agent Shift').agg({'CSAT Score': ['count','sum','mean']}).sort_values(by=['CSAT Score'],ascending=False)

Output
ValueError: The column label 'CSAT Score' is not unique.
For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.

I dont know how to fix so it sorts by the aggregate functions. Any help is appreciate!
This is the output I expect
df.groupby('Agent Shift')['CSAT Score'].count().sort_values(ascending=False)`

Output
Agent Shift
Morning      41426
Evening      33677
Afternoon     5840
Split         3648
Night         1316

I am able to sort it separately, but I want to be able to for all agg in one sit
